# Activate Powerpivot add-in through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, excel-addins

I only have very limited VBA skills, thus I'm need need of help in answering whether it is possible to activate Add-ins in excel through VBA?
A report I'm working on needs to have an activated Powerpivot add-in, thus I want to make a button to active the application.

To fully understand what I am talking about, the pathflow I want is:

> Excel -> File -> Options -> Add-Ins -> Manage -> COM Add-Ins -> Microsoft Office Powerpivot for Excel 2013

Comment: Could [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=25042) be what you want?